# Chrome Highlight unread link

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, django-forms, django-templates

All,

I know this is a fairly straightforward question, but I'm struggling with why this no longer works.  In my css I have the following definition:

```
.table1 td a {
  color: orange;
}
```

When I open up the page in Microsoft Edge, as expected the unread links are in fact orange.  When I do this in Chrome, it appears that Chrome already thinks this link is read.  This used to work, but seems like it stopped working in the last week or two.  I'm running Chrome on a Windows 10 machine, and it's up to date. The version of Chrome is Version 64.0.3282.140 (Official Build) (64-bit).  Anyone else experience this problem?

Here is the associated HTML...

```
<table class="table1" style="width:82%">
  <col style="width:18%">
  <col style="width:20%">
  <col style="width:20%">
  <col style="width:40%">
<tr>
    <th class="title88" colspan=1>From</th>
    <th class="title88" colspan=1>Received</th>
    <th class="title88" colspan=1>Type</th>
    <th class="title88" colspan=1>Name</th>
</tr>
<tbody>
{% for email in email_list %}
<tr>
<td colspan=1><a href="{{ email.get_absolute_url }}"><h2 class="title4">{{email.sender}}</h2></td></a>
<td colspan=1><a href="{{ email.get_absolute_url }}"><h2 class="title4">{{ email.timestamp }}</h2></td></a>
<td colspan=1><a href="{{ email.get_absolute_url }}"><h2 class="title4">{{ email.subject }}</h2></td></a>
<td colspan=1><a href="{{ email.get_absolute_url }}"><h2 class="title4">{{ email.procedure_name }}</h2></td></a>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
</tbody>
```

So weird it briefly worked today and then stopped again.

Comment: Can we see your HTML that accompanies this?

Comment: Please mark your own answer as correct, so that it is clear that this issue is solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be working again for the most part.  I believe I got a Chrome update sometime today and after I rebooted my machine the hightlighting seems to mostly be working.  I didn't alter any of my CSS that I posted.  Problem persists today.  Not sure what is happening.  Not acknowledging answer until issue is resolved.  Turns out needed to clear browsing data from all time for some reason.  Was doing the default time range for all other CSS changes as I've done them throughout my application build, but in this case needed to go further back for some reason.  Spent hours trying to figure this one out.  Hope it helps future Googlers.